# Why Yii never renders errorView on YII_DEBUG = TRUE?

Tags: debugging, yii2

I noticed that yii always shows errors (and exceptions) as plain unformated page.
And I liked to create a nice error view with helpfull debug infos ect.

In yii code and documentation I discovered the config options

```
'errorHandler' => [
  'errorAction' => 'site/error',
  'errorAction' => ... , 
  'errorView' => .... 
]
```

First I was wondering the defined action was never called, after some research I discovered, that [yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException() at line 105](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.46/framework/web/ErrorHandler.php#L105) will only use the renderView when YII_DEBUG is false.

What I like to have:

- I want that a renderView is always displayed (with YII_DEBUG and without it)
- But I like to define one View for Production that shows no details about the error (like it currently alreay is) and for YII_DEBUG I like to show a different view file that gives details error informations.

I like to create a helpfull error page for debugging like this [debug-page](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1390554/27463755-382577ac-57fc-11e7-87e5-80eb39db0683.png).

My Idea was to add:

```
'errorHandler' => [
  'errorAction' => 'site/error',
  'errorAction' => ... , 
  'errorView' => YII_DEBUG 
     ? '@frontend/view/error-debug' 
     : '@frontend/view/error-simple-message' 
]
```

The problem is, that errorView is never used when YII_DEBUG is aktiv.

My question is now, is there a way to reach this goal WITHOUT rewrriting the whole code of the yii ErrorHandler class.

Comment: just switch to production or set YII_DEBUG to false for testing.

Comment: @InsaneSkull thats exactly my problem... when I set YII_DEBUG to true, it does no longer render any views, it yust displays an unformated error in plaintext. I want to create a custom view for the ErrorPage when YII_DEBUG is aktive

Comment: why? Debug is mode for development purpose where you need to see actual errors. You want something forced then extend the ErrorHandler and customize as per your need.

Comment: @InsaneSkull I aggree, that is the reason why I like to create a nice view where you see all error details and some extra context informations that help for debugging (_SERVER ect.) - something like this: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1390554/27463755-382577ac-57fc-11e7-87e5-80eb39db0683.png

I yust hoped there is a way, to enable the exceptionView for debug Mode without rewriting everything.

Comment: Customization is a way to go then.